# How to get number of days of a month given the particular month and year?

Tags: mysql

I am new to sql and programming so please bear with me. Is there a function in mysql that gets the number of days in a month? Example if the month is February and the year 2012 it should return 29. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to find out number of days in month in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736989/how-to-find-out-number-of-days-in-month-in-mysql)

Comment: SELECT DAYOFMONTH(LAST_DAY(now()));

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's no direct "last day of month", but you can fake it by doing a day(last_day())

```
mysql> select last_day('2012-02-22'), day(last_day('2012-02-22'));
+------------------------+-----------------------------+
| last_day('2012-02-22') | day(last_day('2012-02-22')) |
+------------------------+-----------------------------+
| 2012-02-29             |                          29 | 
+------------------------+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

`last_day()` returns the full date of the last day in in the year/month of a specified date, so you then simply use `day()` to extract the day of that last_day.

MySQL's date/time functions documentation is here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: How about getting the all previous no of days. If 2012-02-22 is given output should be Jan-2012 31 and Feb-2012 29

Comment: DAYOFMONTH(LAST_DAY(d.TimeStamp)) AS days   # Day is  Synonym for DAYOFMONTH()