# how to find out number of days in month in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have several dates in mysql tables, using those dates I need to find out the number of days in the month. Suppose i have 2003-02-05 it should return 28. for example

```
date                days_in_month
2003-2-3            28
```

Answer (score 97, accepted):

```
SELECT DAY(LAST_DAY(yourdate))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT DAYOFMONTH(LAST_DAY(your_date)) FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 3):

You can combine LAST_DAY with string function

```
SELECT RIGHT( LAST_DAY(  '2003-02-03' ) , 2 )
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
select DAY(LAST_DAY(yourdate)) as days_in_month
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to string-chopping is to use:

```
SELECT DAY(LAST_DAY('2010-02-1'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use following statement

```
SELECT DAY(LAST_DAY(now()))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking the total number of days to be returned for a month.
If you are trying to find the total number of days for current month, here is the query:

```
select timestampdiff(day,
concat(year(now()),'-',month(now()),'-01'),
date_add( concat(year(now()),'-',month(now()),'-01'), interval 1 month)).
```

If you want to externalize this using any programming language, externalize year and month in the code and replace that with now()