# SQL Query calculate Number of Days in a month

Tags: sql, postgis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to find out number of days in month in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736989/how-to-find-out-number-of-days-in-month-in-mysql)

I need to calculate number of days in a particular month. Let' say if user given 11-25-2012. query needs to return it as 30. Please help me in writing sql code in Postgres.

Thanks in Advance.
Naveen

Comment: [What have you tried ?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: here is a function for postgres that may help with this sort of thing. http://mssql-to-postgresql.blogspot.com/2006/04/dateadd.html

Comment: Although the question is the same as [SO 10736989](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736989/how-to-find-out-number-of-days-in-month-in-mysql), the answer for PostgreSQL is different from the answer for MySQL (because it appears that PostgreSQL does not have a built-in LAST_DAY function, so you have to write one to be able to use it).  See [PostgreSQL Wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Date_LastDay) for example.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  DATE_PART('days', DATE_TRUNC('month', NOW())
 + '1 MONTH'::INTERVAL -    DATE_TRUNC('month', NOW()))
```

Here you just need to give your month number or your date instead of now()

Comment: Hi Mari

SELECT  DATE_PART('days', DATE_TRUNC('month', '11-25-2012') + '1 MONTH'::INTERVAL -    DATE_TRUNC('month', '11-25-2012'));

I tried it in this way but their was a error saying.

Error: function date_trunc(unknown, unknown) is not unique.

I googled about it but unable to understand the reason,Im new to postgres along with it could please explain me what happens with interval.

Comment: Hi @Naveen. Now() function in example is a date. Now you are replacing it with '11-25-2012' which is literally a character. So give your date field or convert your string to char (ie) to_date('11-25-2012', 'DD-MM-YYYY')

Comment: Here is the query to find number of days of that particular month in a given date
SELECT DATE_PART('day', DATE_TRUNC('day',(date_trunc('MONTH',to_Date('2013-02-03','YYYY-mm-dd') ) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 day')))
Thanks to all who helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Works in ***mysql*** :

```
SELECT DAY(LAST_DAY('2003-02-05'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare @DateTimeE  datetime=Convert(Datetime,'03-25-2012',101)
Declare @days int
Select @days= DATEDIFF(Day, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@DateTimeE),0),DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@DateTimeE)+1,0)))+1
select @days

Comment: You can pass any date in  @DateTimeE variable and get days from current months