# Current month datetime count in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want the current month date count in MySQL query not related to any table.

like,

Current month: June
count: 30 (days in the month)

how to do without any relationship with table ???

Comment: Maybe this helps also
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736989/how-to-find-out-number-of-days-in-month-in-mysql/10737040

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `last_day()` to get the last day of the month.  And then `day()` to extract the `day()` number:

```
select day(last_day(now())) as days_in_current_month
```